# multiple criteria for sumifs

Tags: loops, excel, vba

I have two sheets: one is **input** and the other is **master**.

A snapshot of my `input` sheet is shown below:

```
Workers Name     WEEK     working hrs
a11              w1       40
a22              w5       30
a33              w9       10
a44              w10      80
```

A snapshot of my `master` sheet is shown below (NB: the workers names are unique)

```
Workers Name    W1   W2   W3   W4   W5   W6   W7   W8   W9   W10    
a11             40                            
a22                                 30
a33                                                     10
a44                                                          80
```

I want a sumifs loop so that it can give result for workers working hrs in my masters table in their respective weeks(w1 to w13).

I am using a sum ifs formula for this:

```
Sheets("Master").Range("B2:B" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Formula = "=SUMIFS(Input!C32,Input!C37,Master!C1,Input!C31,Master!B1)"
```

Any suggestions how to loop it in VBA

Please help....

Comment: What code have you tried to achieve your goal?

Comment: For rw = 2 To LastRow
    
    Sheets("Master").Cells(rw, 2).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Sheets("Input").Range("AF:AF"), Sheets("Input").Range("AK:AK"), Sheets("Master").Range("A2").Value, Sheets("Input").Range("AE:AE"), Sheets("Master").range("B1"))  next

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry but I'm not sure you need vba - if you know what your row and column criteria are in master you can write something like

```
 =sumifs(workinghrs,workersname,$a2,week,b$2)
```

Then fill it down and across for your grid.

NB I've used named ranges for your input sheet for readability